# android-studio on kali linux 32 bit

Tags: android

Problem report

I have installed android studio 2.3.1 on Linux 32 bit machine (Kali Linux). It is successfully installed. Then after I've tried to create an application the following errors happened.

1. When I run an application on the external device, it will generate the following error:

Error message:

> Unable to detect adb version, adb output:
>   /home/elsi/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: 1:
>   /home/elsi/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb: Syntax error: ")"
>   unexpected

I tried the following solution on the terminal

```
elsi@kali-Rolling:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb kill-server

elsi@kali-Rolling:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb start-server
```

- daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
- daemon started successfully *

`elsi@kali-Rolling:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb devices`

List of devices attached

793532E2034CF208    device

The following are the latest android sdk and gradle version,  I am currently using

```
  compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

Still, the problem is not fixed.

2. When I create a virtual device(emulator) to run the program, it also generates an error says HAXM require genuine Intel processor. I tried to search some solution on the Internet, but Kali Linux does not support this processor, therefore, I installed KVM, and other required packages still not yet supported.
   Error message:

   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first,
Verify that the machine you are running on has an Intel processor. If it's not an Intel processor then try to check what version your kali is: 32bit/64bit.

usually The following platforms are supported by the Intel HAXM:

Windows 8 and 8.1 (32/64-bit), Windows 7 (32/64-bit), Windows Vista* (32/64-bit)

Mac OS X* 10.6 (32/64-bit) or 10.7 (32/64-bit) or 10.8 (64-bit) or 10.9 (64-bit)

Ubuntu (64-bit)

refer to [Link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

second,
try to use arm images for Emulator. You can find this in Other Images tab at the time of emulator creation.

third,
Check if your CPU supports hardware virtualization, by typing:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

If the result is 0, your CPU does not support hardware virtualization, which is necessary to run the KVM. If you get 1 or more, that means you’re fine.

Next, install KVM. First make sure if your processor supports KVM by typing:

```
kvm-ok
```

You will see this if that’s the case:

INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions INFO: /dev/kvm exists KVM acceleration can be used
If this is the result, you need to turn on Intel VT in BIOS:

INFO: KVM is disabled by your BIOS HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT), and then hard poweroff/poweron your system KVM acceleration can NOT be used
The next step is to install the KVM and a few other packages needed. To do so, type:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Add your user to some groups, replacing by your own username:

```
sudo adduser <user> libvirtd

sudo adduser <user> kvm
```

Check if everything is ok:

```
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

Try Again...

let me know if you got it work.

Comment: I have changed my Kali Linux 32 bit to 64 bit and then I installed 32-bit dependencies. It is now working perfectly. Thanks in advance